# Any suggestion to split genres into multiple columns

Tags: sql, data-cleaning

I'm working on cleaning data and planning to split genre into multiple columns. Below is the genre that I see. Genres are divided by so many different ways. Some are divided by / or -, and some has divided by "space", and some movies has different genre name such as anime, animation.
Please suggest a way to split these into multiple columns.
Below is the link if you would like to download the raw data.

https://www.kaggle.com/luiscorter/netflix-original-films-imdb-scores

```
GENRE
Action
Action comedy
Action thriller
Action/Comedy
Action/Science fiction
Action-adventure
Action-thriller
Adventure
Adventure/Comedy
Adventure-romance
Aftershow / Interview
Animated musical comedy
Animation
Animation / Comedy
Animation / Musicial
Animation / Science Fiction
Animation / Short
Animation/Christmas/Comedy/Adventure
Animation/Comedy/Adventure
Animation/Musical/Adventure
Animation/Superhero
Anime / Short
Anime/Fantasy
Anime/Science fiction
Anthology/Dark comedy
Biographical/Comedy
Biopic
Black comedy
Christian musical
Christmas comedy
Christmas musical
Christmas/Fantasy/Adventure/Comedy
Comedy
Comedy / Musical
Comedy horror
Comedy mystery
Comedy/Fantasy/Family
Comedy/Horror
Comedy-drama
Coming-of-age comedy-drama
Concert Film
Crime drama
Crime thriller
Dance comedy
Dark comedy
Documentary
Drama
Drama / Short
Drama/Horror
Drama-Comedy
Family
Family film
Family/Christmas musical
Family/Comedy-drama
Fantasy
Heist
Heist film/Thriller
Hidden-camera prank comedy
Historical drama
Historical-epic
Horror
Horror anthology
Horror comedy
Horror thriller
Horror/Crime drama
Horror-thriller
Making-of
Mentalism special
Mockumentary
Musical
Musical / Short
Musical comedy
Musical/Western/Fantasy
Mystery
One-man show
Political thriller
Psychological horror
Psychological thriller
Psychological thriller drama
Romance
Romance drama
Romantic comedy
Romantic comedy/Holiday
Romantic comedy-drama
Romantic drama
Romantic teen drama
Romantic teenage drama
Romantic thriller
Satire
Science fiction
Science fiction adventure
Science fiction thriller
Science fiction/Action
Science fiction/Drama
Science fiction/Mystery
Science fiction/Thriller
Sports film
Sports-drama
Spy thriller
Stop Motion
Superhero
Superhero/Action
Superhero-Comedy
Supernatural drama
Teen comedy horror
Teen comedy-drama
Thriller
Urban fantasy
Variety show
War
War drama
War-Comedy
Western
Zombie/Heist
```

Comment: You should not use separate columns. You should use a single column in a separate table, one row per genre, joined by a junction table.